# How to remove focus rectangle from a button control?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need to remove a button focus rectangle, because it looks bad over the `TBitBtn` glyph after the buttons is clicked.

Comment: may be setting `Focused := false;` in the OnClick after all?

Comment: Or use a speedbutton instead?

Comment: Both answers were great,thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 6):

You can create an Interposer class for `TBitBtn` and override `SetButtonStyle` preventing it's internal `IsFocused` variable to be set:

```
type
  TBitBtn = class(Buttons.TBitBtn)
  protected
    procedure SetButtonStyle(ADefault: Boolean); override;
  end;

...
implementation

procedure TBitBtn.SetButtonStyle(ADefault: Boolean);
begin
  inherited SetButtonStyle(False);
end;
```

This will result a `TBitBtn` with no focus rectangle. (Tested with D7 - with/without Theme support).

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you can use a `TSpeedButton`, which does not take the focus and, consequently, never receives a focus rectangle.