# Delphi: Return focus after save button is pressed

Tags: delphi, focus

I have a form (modal) with a save button. Keep in mind that this button is not closing the form after is pressed and become disabled after data are saved.

What I would like to do is to return the focus to latest object component used (edit, vst, combobox, etc) after save button was pressed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316831/how-to-remove-focus-rectangle-from-a-button-control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a specialized button that would save the previously focused control while it is receiving focus:

```
type
  TSaveButton = class(TButton)
  private
    FPrevWinControl: TWinControl;
  protected
    procedure Click; override;
    procedure WMSetFocus(var Message: TWMSetFocus); message WM_SETFOCUS;
  end;

procedure TSaveButton.WMSetFocus(var Message: TWMSetFocus);
begin
  FPrevWinControl := FindControl(Message.FocusedWnd);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TSaveButton.Click;
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(FPrevWinControl) then
    FPrevWinControl.SetFocus;
end;
```

This however requires some specialized handling for some controls that have more than one window. E.g. a combobox, if the edit window is focused, `FindControl` won't find the combobox, you need to pass the parent of the edit.

Can also handle it on form level, for instance by overriding `SetFocusedControl`:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
    procedure ButtonSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FPrevWinControl: TWinControl;
  public
    function SetFocusedControl(Control: TWinControl): Boolean; override;
    ...

function TForm1.SetFocusedControl(Control: TWinControl): Boolean;
begin
  if Control = ButtonSave then
    FPrevWinControl := ActiveControl;
  Result := inherited SetFocusedControl(Control);
end;

procedure TForm1.ButtonSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // save ...
  if Assigned(FPrevWinControl) then
    FPrevWinControl.SetFocus;
end;
```

Comment: second variant looks better. thank you for your answer Sertac Akyuz